# The service return failed.the error message is Server certificate is invalid

Tags: push, libgit2

I have used tortoiseGit and been able to push. Or with cmd prompt without issue. when I used libgit2,the server return failed.
Any successful workarounds. Will it be supported?

Comment: Can you tell us more about your server's configuration?  Is it a self-signed certificate or one signed by a trusted CA?  What does your _git_ configuration look like?  When you installed git did you select OpenSSL or schannel?

Comment: @EdwardThomson Thanks!The https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/issues/4878 is the same as my quesition.